# Updating minimum value in java-stream

Tags: java, java-stream

```
openSet.stream()
   .filter(vertex -> distance.get(vertex) < min)
   .forEach(vertex -> {
      current = vertex;
      min = distance.get(vertex);
   });
```

I want to iterate through the vertex in my openSet where the distance is less than the min (set to infinity at the beginning). Then I want to loop through each of these filtered vertex and update `current` to the minimum vertex and `min` to the value of the minimum vertex.

I think it should be along the lines of creating a map and a comparator?

`distance` map is defined as:

```
Map<Integer, Double> distance = new HashMap<>();
```

It contains the vertex number as key and the shortest distance from source. I am doing A*Star path finding algorithm.

Comment: Lambda expression wont allow you to update variables outside the lambda. What is the purpose of setting `current` and `min` variables?

Comment: `minVertex = Collections.min(openSet, Comparator.comparing(distance::get))` would give you the vertex with minimum distance already. You don't have to implement it yourself. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem, this is what you try to do:

```
for (SomeClass vertex :  openSet) {
    if (distance.get(vertex) < min) {
        current = vertex;
        min = distance.get(vertex);
    }
}
```

No need to use streams for this.